# New tag proposal: Variable Kolmogorov Complexity

Tags: discussion, tags

I was thinking maybe we should have a tag for those things that are kind of like kolmogorov complexity, in that it is a no-input output challenge, but not quite.

For those challenges where a output from no input is needed, but is just something that obeys certain rules, rather than one specific output. The output may or may not be deterministic.

Might need a better name. Probably post something if you have one.

Examples of challenges in this category:

- [Please do my martian homework](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101727/please-do-my-martian-homework)
- [5 favourite letters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99913/5-favorite-letters)
- [Print some JSON](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97305/print-some-json)

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9886/8478) (Although I think you mean a lot more "variable" than the discussion in the linked post.)

Comment: A different kind of variable. I'm not really satisfied with the title for some reasons including that one

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a dupe of http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9886/45941 - the consensus opinion on that question was that non-constant-output challenges can still fall under [tag:kolmogorov-complexity].

Comment: but usually these ARE (mostly) constant output challenges, it's just that programmer choice factors into the output of the program as a main component, and I think that these sorts of questions are interesting

Comment: I'm not sure this tag is necessary, but if it is then it *definitely* needs a *shorter* name. The length limit is 25 chars.

Comment: I know that... maybe answerer choice, or something